# Using Reactivecocoa login button only triggered once

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

Here is my basic scenario:

I am making a simple `login` framework, so I got two `text field`, one for username and the other for password, and of course a login `button`.

Now I bind them with `RACSignal` like this:

```
RACSignal *validPasswordSignal = [passwordTextField.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text)
{
    return @([self isPasswordValid:text]);
}];

RACSignal *validUsernameSignal = [usernameTextField.rac_textSignal map:^id(NSString *text)
{
    return @([self isUsernameValid:text]);
}];
```

And combine two signals (username and password) into one like this:

```
RACSignal *submitActiveSignal = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[validpasswordSignal, validUsernameSignal] reduce:^id(NSNumber *validPW, NSNumber *validUN)
{
    return @(validPW.boolValue && validUN.boolValue);
}];
```

Of course I need a method to submit signals for username and password with request to server, so I have it like this:

```
-(RACSignal *)submitSignal
{
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber)
    {
        [[[RequestClass alloc] init] requestWithUsername:_usernameTextField.text.trim password:_passwordTextField.text.trim completionHandler:^(MyResult *results, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
        {
            if (!error)
            {
                if (results.code == 0)
                {
                    [subscriber sendNext:@(YES)];
                    [subscriber sendCompleted];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSError *invalidError = [NSError errorWithDomain:MyErrorDomain code:MyErrorInvalidSigniture userInfo:@{@"NSLocalizedDescription": results.message}];
                    [subscriber sendError:invalidError];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
            }
        }];
        return nil;
    }];
}
```

Then I need to let my login button catch the signal from subscriber's `sendNext` and `sendError`, so I did it like this:

```
//subscribeNext
[[[[_submitButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
doNext:^(id x)
{
    _submitButton.enabled = NO;
}]
flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value)
{
    return [self submitSignal];
}]
subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *signal)
{
    _submitButton.enabled = YES;
    BOOL success = signal.boolValue;
    if (success)
    {
        [self successCallback];
    }
    else
    {
        //do sth
    }
}];

//subscribeError
[[[[_submitButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
doNext:^(id x)
{
    _submitButton.enabled = NO;
}]
flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value)
{
    return [self submitSignal];
}]
subscribeError:^(NSError *error)
{
    [self failureCallbackWithError:error];
}];
```

Above is the `reactivecocoa` code I wrote for my login procedure. When the pass and username was correct, the signal would go to `sendNext`'s response block: `subscribeNext`,
but the issue is, when the credentials were incorrect, and server returned error, neither the `sendError` nor `subscribeError` would be triggered.

It's like the error signal was lost or something.

I'm not sure if I am using the right reactivecocoa methods to handle success signal and error signal.

So please help, thanks.

Also please let me know if I'm not clear on my question.

Comment: I don't know if this will fix the error problem, but you shouldn't be subscribing to the button touch event twice - you'll send two requests each time it's tapped. Use `subscribeNext:error` to handle both success and failure in a single subscription.

Comment: @PatrickBacon I tried your way but still not working. I clicked the button once and it triggered either subscribeNext block or the error block which is good; but when I clicked the button the second time, nothing happened. In the `trigger` method I put `[subscriber sendNext:@(YES)]; [subscriber sendCompleted]` and `[subscriber sendError:error]`. Would you pls take a look and help me out?

Comment: Make sure you are re-enabling the button in both your success (`subscribeNext:`) and error (`error:`) cases. You should probably also add a `deliverOnMainThread` after the `flattenMap` to make sure the changes to the UI are happening on the main thread.

Comment: @PatrickBacon Actually I have done this re-enabling thing. Actually the button can be tapped over and over again since once my finger tapped on it, its color changed, getting darker actually, meaning the state was changing to `highlighted`. But nothing happened then. Only the first time it would trigger its event.

Comment: @Boris Hi , I am facing same prblm in my project so can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `RACCommand` and it will take care of a lot of this for you:

```
@weakify(self)
RACCommand *submitCommand = 
    [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:submitActiveSignal signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        @strongify(self)
        return [[self submitSignal]
            doCompleted:^{
                @strongify(self)
                [self successCallback];
            }];
    }];

_submitButton.rac_command = submitCommand;
```

By providing the `submitActiveSignal` as the `initWithEnabled:` argument the button will automatically be enabled/disabled based on the value emitted from that signal.

For error handling, `RACCommand` has a special `errors` signal that sends every error that occurs in the command. You could subscribe to the `errors` signal to handle all errors that result from your signal returned from inside the command:

```
[[submitCommand.errors 
    takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal]
    subscribeNext:^(NSError *error) {
        @strongify(self)
        [self failureCallbackWithError:error];
    }];
```

And don't forget to `@weakify`/`@strongify` references to `self` inside of signals to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yeah I actually know about this way. But I am trying to figure out what issue there is in my way so I could really understand the mechanism of RAC.